# issues installing rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rspec

So I'm trying to install rspec to do my testing with my new rails app.

here is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'


gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and here is the script i run to install it

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

The error it gives me its that it can't find gem 'rails_12 factor' and to run bundle install to install the missing gems I ran it still gave me the same error. I even tried taking rails_12factor out of the production group but no good. I am using a windows machine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try run it for `production` environment (for [unix](/questions/tagged/unix)-like system):

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails generate rspec:install
```

for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)-like system:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
rails generate rspec:install
```

or just move the `rails_12factor` [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) out of the `production` group:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
end
```

Comment: just taking it out of the production group running bundle update then bundle install and still says it can't find it i thought rails automatically installed it when i ran it

Comment: and i tried running the "RAILS_ENV=production rails generate rspec:install" command but it tells me rails_env is not recongized as a command

Comment: @user3051232 `rails_env is not recongized ` you should not insert spaces here `RAILS_ENV=production` to the command. retry please

Comment: im sorry where shouldn't i insert spaces? I copied a pasted your first code

Comment: and another question, for what do you put the gem into production group?

Comment: @user3051232 that is stragmenly becaise I don't get any such error on the command, please retry, and copy text screenshot, to your question post.

Comment: the issue was that for windows you need to insert set before the RAILS_ENV command

Comment: @user3051232 try update, and that is you need it to declare the RAILS_ENV variable setting it to `production` value

Comment: the version of ruby on windows is unstable i had to downgrade back to 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

to anyone who is having the same issue your probably running ruby 2.0.0 x64 which is very buggy and this is one of the examples the only solution is to get ruby 1.9.3.